# Input past end of file VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to read text file (these files are produced by external program, that could not be tweeked) using the following macro.

```
    While Not EOF(int_current_file)
    Line Input #int_current_file, buf
    If Left(buf, 1) <> "#" Then
        buf1 = Split(buf, "=")
        Print #int_master_file, CInt(Left(buf, 2)) & ";" & CInt(Mid(buf, 3, 4)) & ";" & CInt(Mid(buf, 7, 3)) & ";" & CInt(Mid(buf, 10, 1)) & ";" & CDbl(buf1(1) / 100000000) & ";" & CDate(file_date) & ";" & Mid(file_name, 4, 3)
    End If
    'Line Input #int_current_file, buf
    'Debug.Print Data
Wend
```

However, at the second line of this file I have the following string:

`=01082013=01072013=31072013=06082013=1640=380441=21=000001249=#02IFS86.G84=IFSSS5=7ҐK!Ђi—Љ42ЃЁ4№{¤Хo$]ґ•Хp Ё1‹;±~†ЁRLЌг‰®ґн нќРР^±>_‰`

When macro tries to read this line the `error 62` occurs `Input past end of file`.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

May I interest you in a better way of reading text files in VBA?

This will read the entire text file in `ONE GO` in an array and then close the file. This way you don't need to keep the file open at all times.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Replace your file here
    Open "C:\MyFile.Txt" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    '
    '~~> Now strData has all the data from the text file
    '

    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        Debug.Print strData(i)
        '
        '~~> What ever you want here
        '
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please post comments on this peace of code:                   MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData?

Comment: `Space$(LOF(1))` creates a string the size of the file. [LOF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtz29k5z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and `Space$` is to initialize the string to a given length. By the way, did it work for you?

Comment: Hi, I have been flabergasted by the difficulty of importing a simple text file in VBA!. It seems to be easier to extract data straight from a website than just importing them from a text file. Yours is the 20th suggestion I have tried and it does not work for me either. I'm just trying to important text files as a string so that I can use 'Mid' and 'InStr' functions on the resulting string. Any clarification would be more than welcome. If I try to put strData in a TextBox I get an error: "type mismatch" I'm guessing this is due to the array rather than string type? Any solutions?